# Is there an easier HTML Path method than repeating ../?

Tags: html, css, path

Really basic question, some advise would be great please.
All of my web images and CSS are of course organised in my root. I then have a catalogue folder, which branches out into 3-4 deeper sub categories. In my HTML its becoming a bit messy sourcing my images/css because I'm using a lot of:

`../`

```
<img src="../../../images/myimage.png" style="width:200px; height:auto;">
```

What do you guys recommend? Do you do this? Or should I sort my images relevant to that file into their sub categories? Thanks, as always.

C:\Users\sam\Desktop\webroot\catalogue\folder1\folder2\folder3

Comment: Did you try `<base href` ?

Comment: I didn't know about this, what would my code be?
<base href="" target="_blank">

Comment: Something like this -> if your image is located in `yourdomain/images` set `<base href="yourdomain"/>`

Comment: ahh I like it! works great, I can define the root in my header and simplify all the paths in the rest of my HTML. Post this as your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `base` for this see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

> The HTML  element specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document. There can be only one  element in a document.

For example if your folder structure is like yourdomain/images set 
`<base href="yourdomain"/>`

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct method of doing it. Rather than sorting images in relevant folder you can keep it in the separate folder only as you did.

There is a way of minimizing this no of times of `../`

Don't assign the `src` directly in line of the tag.
Always prefer separate `css` file or `javascript` file to do that.
You can put all your `css` files in one folder and you can keep that folder nearer to your `images` folder.

So that you can use only one `../`. it'll look like `../images/yourimage.png`

Suppose your html file's location is like 
`\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\sample.html`

And your image files are in `\1\images\`
you can place all the `javascript` files in a folder which is nearer to the `images` folder like this `\1\scripts\`

Now suppose in your `sample.html` file there were lot of image tags like below

```
<img height="200" width="200" class="nature"/>
<img height="200" width="200" class="nature"/>
<img height="200" width="200" class="nature"/>
```

you can just import the `javascript` file like this

```
<script src="../../../../../../../../scripts/myscripts.js"></script>
```

Note: this is the only place you are going to use lengthy `../`

In `myscripts.js` file you can simply use

```
$(".nature").attr("src","../images/yourimage.png");
```

Similarly you can do this for the rest of the tags also.
So in that `javascript you need not to use lengthy locations.

You may have 100s of `img` tags. you can simply import this `js` file only one time and use it.

Comment: But say for example: I have a folder, inside is another, inside that is another... until x20. I would then have to use ../ 20 times? Bit silly?

Comment: yeah. If your folder structure is like that, then you have to.. Otherwise just follow the `css` file concept as I said it above. Because in that way you can minimize the length of the location.